# Where is ID3D10EffectShaderResourceVariable::SetResourceArray in SlimDX?

Tags: slimdx, directx10

I don't know if I'm just not looking in the right place, but I can't find ID3D10EffectShaderResourceVariable::SetResourceArray anywhere in SlimDX.

Anyone have any idea how I should be calling this?

Comment: I checked SlimDX trunk and it doesn't have this function exposed for some reason (`SlimDX.Direct3D11.EffectResourceVariable.SetResourceArray()` is there as expected). 

I don't know why `ID3D10EffectShaderResourceVariable->SetResourceArray()` is absent, and even though it seems easy to expose it yourself, maybe it's better to ask SlimDX devs on their Gamedev forum or hope that @Josh Petrie will answer here :)

Comment: @Vigil - yeah that's what I thought. I've asked on Gamedev but no answer so far.

Comment: @Vigil I don't think the system pings me if you @ me in comment on a question where I have not participated yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/issues/detail?id=829) in SlimDX; we just left the method out. It was fixed in [revision 2134](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/source/detail?r=2134) and should be in the binaries for our September release (which, the name notwithstanding, was shipped in October a few days ago).

You can simply call `SetResourceArray` with an array of shader resource views on any `EffectResourceVariable` now.